# Binding IsEnabled to Text.Length only works one way

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, textbox, isenabled

I have a TextBox, which I want to be enabled only if another TextBox has text in it. I am binding the Text.Length property of the first TextBox to the IsEnabled property on the second box. I have also tried binding the Text property of the first box and using a converter to convert to a bool. Both methods result in the second box being enabled when text is entered into the first but when the text is deleted the second box isn't disabled.

I have tried setting NotifyOnSourceUpdated and NotifyOnTargetUpdated to true but neither has any effect.

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1"/>
<TextBox Name="textBox2" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Text.Length}"/>
```

So my question is what is needed for textBox2 to be disabled when the text in textBox1 is deleted.

Comment: Yes and I have subsequently found it is working in another class in the project so I do not know why it is not working here.

Comment: I'm guessing this works because WPF is using System.Convert.ToBoolean which returns true for all but zero

Answer (score 2):

This should work -

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1"/>
<TextBox Name="textBox2">
   <TextBox.Style>
       <Style TargetType="TextBox">
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=textBox1}"
                                     Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Issue with your code is you are binding `IsEnabled` `bool` property to `Text.Length` property whose type is `int`. So, either you need to use the `converter` or do it through `triggers` as i posted above.

Comment: There seems to be some automatic conversion. OP's example XAML works out of the box for me.

Comment: Yeh a trigger is not needed, you can user a converter on the binding to bind IsEnabled to Text but there is an automatic conversion for Text.Length.